# mini-css-extract-plugin TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

I have been using mini-css-extract-plugin for a while for my css module dynamic import but suddenly it was breaking webpack build.

It is webpack 4

Answer (score 0):

One of the issue in the git board had solution but its not working

"Update to latest version of webpack"

Currently, webpack latest one has its own issue so working versions are

```
"webpack": "4.19.1",
"webpack-cli": "3.1.2",
```

Comment: Were you using webpack4 prior? Also, can you post your webpack.config.js and stack trace?